# How to select appropriate positive and negative training image sets for image classification using BOW

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

Im trying implement a real time object classification program using SVM classification and BoW clustering algorithms. My questions is what are the good practices for selecting positive and negative training images?

**Positive image sets**

- Should the background be empty? ***Meaning, should the image only contain the object of interest? When implementing this algorithm in real time, the test image will not contain only the object of interest***, it will definitely have some information from the background as well. ***So instead of using isolated image collection, should I choose images which look more similar to the test images?***

**Negative image sets**

- Can these be any image set without the object of interest? Or should they be from the environment where this algorithm is going to be tested without object of interest?. ***For example, if I'm going to classify phones in my living room environment, should negatives be the background image set of my living room environment without the phone in the foreground? or can it be any image set? (like kitchen, living room, bedroom or outdoor images) Im asking this because, I don't want the system to be environment-specific. Must be robust at any environment (indoors and outdoors)***

Thank you. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Positive image sets**

Yes you should definitely choose images which look more similar to the test images.

**Negative image sets**

It can be any image set however, it is better to include images from the environment where this algorithm is going to be tested without object of interest.

**Generally**

Please read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003424/how-to-train-opencv-svm-with-bow-properly/28112558#28112558) to some other SO question, it would be useful. Discussion continued in comments, so that might be useful as well.

Comment: Hey @guneykayim thank you for your answer. Really appreciate. How can I develop a system which is truly robust and functional in any environment? What kind of classification/clustering algorithms I should be considering? Is there any specific techniques I can make you use make such a system? Your guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks again :)

Comment: There is no straight forward approach for your question. Robustness, functionality, algorithms, techniques.. They all change according to the problem, you can't use same solution for every system. Every system has its own dynamics and had be investigated and developed individually. Of course some problems share common approaches for their solutions, but no one can say that you can use a specific approach for any kind of problem.

Comment: Hey @guneykayim Bro thank you so much :) Appreciate your answer :) Ill do more research to learn about developing a robust system with keeping your advice in mind :) cheers mate :)